# App crashing when trying to select text from Webview

Tags: android, select, text, webview

When i long press text in the Webview (android), the app crashes. I also can't select text, because it crashes before the text is highlighted. I think that, normally, the app would show the default Contextual Action Bar, right?

What might be happening? Thanks.

Update: here is the log:

> Blockquote
>
> 09-15 23:35:21.680  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
>
> 09-15 23:35:21.681  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
>
> 09-15 23:35:21.771  26033-26043/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro I/art﹕ Debugger is active
>
> 09-15 23:35:21.910  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
>
> 09-15 23:35:21.910  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
>
> 09-15 23:35:22.111  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
>
> 09-15 23:35:22.312  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
>
> 09-15 23:35:22.512  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
>
> 09-15 23:35:22.714  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
>
> 09-15 23:35:22.915  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
>
> 09-15 23:35:23.116  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
>
> 09-15 23:35:23.318  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1383)
>
> 09-15 23:35:23.868  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
>
> 09-15 23:35:23.869  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro I/chromium﹕ [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(116)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
>
> 09-15 23:35:23.952  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro I/BrowserStartupController﹕ Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
>
> 09-15 23:35:23.958  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local SIRT entry from IRT, ignoring
>
> 09-15 23:35:23.991  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro E/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ BLUETOOTH permission is missing!
>
> 09-15 23:35:24.057  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro I/Adreno-EGL﹕ : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU ()
>       OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
>       Build Date: 03/07/14 Fri
>       Local Branch:
>       Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
>       Local Patches: NONE
>       Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 + f2fd134 +  NOTHING
>
> 09-15 23:35:24.104  26033-26228/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/art﹕ Thread[16,tid=26228,Native,Thread*=0x48f0c758,peer=0x6526f030,"Thread-40584"] attached without supplying a name
>
> 09-15 23:35:24.127  26033-26223/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/art﹕ Thread[17,tid=26223,Native,Thread*=0x48ce1740,peer=0x6526ff90,"Thread-40585"] attached without supplying a name
>
> 09-15 23:35:24.202  26033-26228/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(890)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
>
> 09-15 23:35:24.250  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local SIRT entry from IRT, ignoring
>
> 09-15 23:35:24.340  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local SIRT entry from IRT, ignoring
>
> 09-15 23:35:24.406  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local SIRT entry from IRT, ignoring
>
> 09-15 23:35:25.074  26033-26277/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/art﹕ Thread[19,tid=26277,Native,Thread*=0x48ed9778,peer=0x652b6480,"Thread-40588"] attached without supplying a name
>
> 09-15 23:35:25.223  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro D/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ ==> onReceive: s=0, m=0, n=h2w, sb=true
>
> 09-15 23:35:25.226  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro D/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ reportUpdate: state=0, devices=[Speakerphone, Headset earpiece]
>
> 09-15 23:35:26.116  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
>
> 09-15 23:35:26.291  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>
> 09-15 23:35:26.325  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
>
> 09-15 23:35:27.031  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
>
> 09-15 23:35:27.143  26033-26312/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/art﹕ Thread[22,tid=26312,Native,Thread*=0x48f02c50,peer=0x652d35f8,"Thread-40591"] attached without supplying a name
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.842  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.app.ActionBar.getThemedContext()' on a null object reference
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.852  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS.getThemedContext(ActionBarImplICS.java:302)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.855  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJB.getThemedContext(ActionBarImplJB.java:20)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.859  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.getActionBarThemedContext(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:210)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.863  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onActionModeStarted(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:195)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.868  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onActionModeStarted(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:359)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.872  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2437)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.876  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2362)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.879  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.883  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.886  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:665)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.890  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:4554)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.894  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.showSelectActionBar(ContentViewCore.java:2341)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.898  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.access$2200(ContentViewCore.java:93)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.902  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore$13.showHandles(ContentViewCore.java:2154)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.906  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.input.SelectionHandleController.onSelectionChanged(SelectionHandleController.java:168)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.910  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.onSelectionBoundsChanged(ContentViewCore.java:2620)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.914  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.918  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:24)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.921  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.925  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.928  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5088)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.931  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.935  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>
> 09-15 23:35:36.938  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>
> 09-15 23:35:37.040  26033-26033/com.edireito.digimecum.dgpro A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000065b1 (code=-6), thread 26033 (digimecum.dgpro)

Comment: The answer could be in the LogCat...just thinking...

Comment: Run your app in debug mode and post the log of the error you get.

Comment: Thanks, i added the log to the main question! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

After analysing the code, i found that the problem was in the beginning of the Java file. It started with

package com.edireito.dgpro.dgpro;
import...
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

And when i changed "ActionBarActivity"  to "Activity", it worked!

Thanks.